# Is there a better way to deal with certain iterations rather than if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to achieve a fairly complex layout. I've managed to do it but cant help think that the IF statement is a little lacking in refinement.

I have a for loop which loops through grid items, the first item and every 5th one are larger and every second large item is floated to the right rather than the left. There are four small items to every large one in a row (so the large is the same size as the four small).

I just think my IF isnt particularly elegant and also restricts the size of the grid.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) { 
    if ($i % 5 == 0) { ?>
        <article <?php if ($i == 5 || $i == 15 || $i == 25 || $i == 35 || $i == 45 || $i == 55) { ?>style="float:right;" <?php } ?>>
        //do big item
        </article>
    } else { 
        <article>
        //do small item
        </article>
    }
$i++;
}
```

Im also trying to work out how I can wrap every row of 5 items in another div to help with sizing? I was thinking another block of if ($i % 5 == 0) { may help with this but Im conscious of loading times and best practice too.

As always any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your code you are not increasing the value of `$i` how this can work?

Comment: if this is for styling, you could also look into the [CSS nth child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). this is the route i would take.

Comment: Sorry I am in my code, I simplified code above for easy reading. I shall edit it now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just introduce a second mod operator. eg.

```
if ($i % 5 == 0){
 if ( ($i-5) % 10 == 0 ){
   // so this will work for values of %i = 5, 15, 25, 35 ...
   // big article
 }else{
   // small article
 }
$i++ ; // as previous comment @javad pointed out. You are not incrementing i
```

Comment: Cool thanks, this replaces my IF nicely, I can see the math working now its in front of me. I think wrapping every 5 items in their own div will be hard though, if its even possible with my current structure.